# Set initial pager item

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am writing a pager fragment as follows:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.UUID;

public class CommentPagerActivity extends FragmentActivity{
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private ArrayList<Comment> mComments;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
    mViewPager.setId(R.id.viewPager);
    setContentView(mViewPager);

    mComments = CommentLab.get(this).getCommentsArray();    //get commentArray``

    //setting up pagerAdapter
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            Comment comment = mComments.get(position);
            return CommentFragment.newInstance(comment.getId());
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mComments.size();
        }
    });


    //ViewPager by default shows the first comment no matter where u click.
    //to have it show the comment selected, do the following
    UUID commentId =    (UUID)getIntent().getSerializableExtra(CommentFragment.EXTRA_COMMENT_ID);

    for(int i=0; i < mComments.size(); i++){
        if (mComments.get(i).getId().equals(commentId)){
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}

}
```

The pager works, but When I click on an item on the list(lets say the last item), it always initializes the viewPager with the first item on my

```
arrayList(mComments)...
```

what could be wrong?

The app basically has a listView of comments, when someone clicks on an item in the list, it opens CommentsFragment with details about the comment

Comment: Just a guess but you're telling the viewpager to set an item before that it has been created. Try set the item in onCreateView or in onResume and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem.
In my onItemClicked function in CommentListFragment, I did not pass the UUID commentID as an extra to intent!! 
My UUID above was always NULL!
Thanks all